# Going from planes in normal to parametric

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Question: Provide examples of planes parallel to the z-axis. Describe them using parametric equations.

Hello, I am trying to solve this problem with both normal and parametric equations. I figured out that the following planes described in normal information will be parallel to the $z$-axis:

$A(x-x_0)= 0$

$B(y-y_0) = 0$

And their combination

$A(x-x_0) +B(y-y_0)= 0$

I am wondering how can I convert these three planes (in $R^3$) into their parametric form. If anyone has an article or explanation I appreciate it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an obvious example: Plane $2x+3y=0$.In parametric equations, the plane would be $$x=-3s,y=2s, z=t. $$